# Функция, перебирающая строку

Tags: python, строки, list

Как создать функцию, которая перебирает строку до пробела і записує в переменную (до пробела) я питался записати в строку по одному символу (не получилось)

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов много, например, такой:

```
for ch in 'тут что-то написано'.split()[0]:
    print(ch)
```

Comment: Дякую вам помогли

Answer (score -1):

```py
def space_search(string):
    for x in string:
        if x == ' ':
            print('Space')
            break
a = 'test string'
space_search(a)
```

Comment: Спасибі вам  за поміч